# Regular expression character set WITHOUT certain words

Tags: regex

So we have the following regular expression:

`[a-zA-Z\-\_]+\/(.)*`

Which matches strings like:

```
hello/anything
test-page/allSorts1
```

Is there a way we can make the first match, `[a-zA-Z\-\_]\/(.)*` exclude certain words from the character set. For instance, "hello" or "something-else" not to be matched?

I have tried something like: `[a-zA-Z\-\_[^hello][^something\-else]]\/(.)*` and `[a-zA-Z\-\_](?!hello|something-else)\/(.)*` and `[a-zA-Z\-\_](hello|something-else){0}\/(.)*` but none of these work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `\b(?!hello|something-else)[a-zA-Z\-\_]\/(.)*` **MAY** do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead at the start.

```
^(?!.*\b(?:hello|something-else)\b)[a-zA-Z\-\_]+\/(.*)
```

The above regex won't match the lines which has the string `hello` or `somethig-else`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/30)